# Value in request body are not appearing double qouted in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I'm trying to pass some value using a CSV file, some of these data should be passed in the request body as a string with double-quote some others are integer.

currently, all values are passed to the request body without a double quote.

down below you can preview my config, I want the email to pass with a double-quote while the year of birth to be passed as an integer.

[image: variable names]

that's how my request body looks like
[image: that's how my request body looks like]

as you can see below the email and pass..etc are passed to request body without double quote
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update body as {"email":"${email}"}

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to either put quotation marks in the CSV file and **untick** "Allow quoted data" option in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)
2. Or put quotation marks around the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) reference in your request body like:

   ```
    { "email" : "${email}", "password" : "${password}", "etc":""}
   ```